# c3p0 file not found error

Tags: java, servlets, c3p0

I am using c3p0-0.9.2.1 jar and i have this jar in my class path and lib folder.
Whenever i connect for the first Time i get this Error:

```
com.mchange.v2.cfg.DelayedLogItem [ level -> FINE, text -> "The configuration file for resource identifier '/mchange-commons.properties' could not be found. Skipping.", exception -> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resource not found at path '/mchange-commons.properties'.]
com.mchange.v2.cfg.DelayedLogItem [ level -> FINE, text -> "The configuration file for resource identifier 'hocon:/reference,/application,/' could not be found. Skipping.", exception -> java.io.FileNotFoundException: HOCON lib (typesafe-config) is not available. Also, no resource available at '/reference,/application,/' for HOCON identifier 'hocon:/reference,/application,/'.]
```

My application is running fine though.i am not able to gauge what is this error and should i be worried about this error?If yes, how to remove this error.What am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

These are DEBUG level messages, basically documenting c3p0's checking all the various places configuration information can be placed, and usually not finding anything in most of those places. The FileNotFoundExceptions are how c3p0 sees there is nothing there.

c3p0 and libraries under `com.mchange` in general are intended to log at INFO level for normal use. If you log at DEBUG or FINE, you may see more stuff than you'd like, including things like these perfectly harmless an expected FileNotFoundExceptions during the search for config files.

Comment: I'm using slf4j logging (logback) which is configured to only show INFO messages. This works for everything, even some of the c3p0 logging but during startup it is still outputting these messages to standard output.

Comment: is c3p0 logging going through logback? at some point, you should see an initialization message like "INFO: MLog clients using ...", with the ... referencing the logging library being used.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the DelayedLogItem class in the cp30 package and also debugged the code.

It seems this class doesn't use logback or any logger for that matter. Actually it does something similar as most loggers, it defines its own log levels etc. The log message is actually the result of the toString() method.

During debugging I found that the BasicMultiPropertiesConfig class is trying to find some configuration files and when it doesn't it calls a method `dumpToSysErr` which outputs the log lines to standard error.

So it looks like there is no way to use any logger to 'catch' these log message and show it based on your logger configuration.

By the way, if you configure e.g. logback to do TRACE logging on com.mchange, then it also logs using logback (including stacktraces).